# Transfer JavaScript function over REST API

Tags: javascript, json, function, api, transfer

I have to move some config files from the frontend to the backend. Here is an example of the config:

```
    {
      name: 'backend_field_created_at',
      alias: 'createdAt',
      render: (row) => { return (<span>{`${date(row.createdAt)}`}</span>) },
      sortable: true,
      type: 'text'
    }
```

As you can see there are also JavaScript functions and they are very different from each other. The config files should get called from the REST API. What is the best approach for this problem?

Is eval an option here because the source is our server?

Answer (score 1):

I STRONGLY advise against this approach. Not only eval is not safe, but the whole idea of executing code coming from front-end into the back-end and vice-versa seems to fragile for me. 
It can cause trouble with dependencies, modules and security issues for starters.

What I would advise is to create a named list of 'shared' functions, maybe as a npm module, and load at both back-end and front-end. So you could, do as this:

```
{
  name: 'backend_field_created_at',
  alias: 'createdAt',
  fnc_render: 'row_rendering_function_name',
  fnc_parameters: a_serializable_param_list,
  sortable: true,
  type: 'text'
}
```

And, who receives the data should do someting as this:\

```
(data) => { 
    functionList[data.fnc_render](data.fnc_parametes);
}
```

You'll need the functionlist to have you implementation:

```
functionList['row_rendering_function_name'] = (row) => { 
   return (<span>{`${date(row.createdAt)}`}</span>) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the API 100% that it will not return harmful code, then there is nothing against this approach in terms of safety.

However, even if you trust the API perfectly, it is not a good practice to write client-side codes into server-side. When you write server code, you should think only about the server. If you are the only developer of the project, then you might not feel the downside, but if a teammate writes such a code and you will have to take up his or her work and develop it further, that's when the dragons start coming.

You should therefore separate your client-side and server-side and do not use eval unless you are absolutely forced to do so.